# Mi ventana modal no se cierra

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

Estoy creando una ventana modal pero estoy teniendo problemas para cerrarla, el siguiente es un navbar fijo el cual lo ubico como pie de pagina y contiene dos botones, uno de ellos abre mi ventana modal.

El siguiente es el codigo de mi navbar ubicado en el pie de pagina:

```
<div id="accept_cookie_ga4" class="alert alert-infoCookie alert-dismissible fade in navbar-fixed-bottom hide" role="alert">
        <h4>Titulo</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="alert">Aceptar</button>

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="alert" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="Abrir Modal" />

    </div>
```

El siguiente es el código de mi ventana modal que se abre desde el botón `Abrir Modal` ubicado en el navbar

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Titulo de modal</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Modal content...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Se supone que al dar click en el botón **Aceptar** se debe cerrar mi ventana modal pero no lo hace. Como información adicional dejo las versiones de JQuery y Bootstrap.

- Versión JQuery 3.3.1
- Versión Bootstrap 3.3.7

He intentado hacer uso de la siguiente función pero aun así no se me cierra mi ventana modal.

```
<script>
            $(".cerrarModal").click(function () {
                $("#myModal").modal('hide')
            });

        </script>
```

La consola de mi navegador no muestra ningún error por eso no se que es lo que esta fallando.

Comment: Tu botón **Aceptar** no tiene la clase `.cerrarModal`, por lo que la función click que has definido para cerrar la modal no está vinculada a dicho botón. Añádele la clase al botón y te debería de funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de ir y venir y apoyándome de los comentarios a mi pregunta me di cuenta de que no necesito un código Javascript personalizado para cerrar un modal de Bootstrap, siempre que marque los botones de cierre con el `data-dismiss="modal"` atributo (como ya lo estoy haciendo).

Solo necesito quitar el `data-dismiss="alert"` en su botón de alternancia:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="accept_cookie_ga4" class="alert alert-infoCookie alert-dismissible fade in navbar-fixed-bottom" role="alert">
    <h4>Titulo</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="alert">Aceptar</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Abrir Modal
  </button>

</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModal-label">Titulo de modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal content...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

También lo realice en el siguiente [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4g1uepa/)

Y pude tomar como referencia la documentación de Bootstrap v3.3.7 [aquí](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals)

Espero haber ayudado a otra persona que se encontraba con el mismo problema.